# Hoare Logic: Identifying Hoare Triple given a simple function

Tags: algorithms, logic, discrete-mathematics, hoare-logic

> The program is designed to start with values for $x$ and $y$. The variables $u1$​ and $u2$​ are intended to represent $x$ and $y$ in ascending order.
> Provide suitable preconditions and postconditions for the program.
> Then, using Hoare logic, prove the correctness of the program.
> Specify all proof obligations and justify their correctness.
> Note that formal proofs (e.g., using natural deduction) are not required.

Edit I accidentally left out an important detail: "You should consider that the postcondition should be such that we know the initial values of both x and y occur in the set {u1, u2}."

```
if (x < y) {
    u_1 = x;
    u_2 = y;
} else {
    u_1 = y;
    u_2 = x;
}
```

Is the preconditions: $x<y\ \lor\ y<x$ and the postcondition: $u1<u2$ correct?  Right now I only need help with defining correct pre- and postconditions.

Comment: What if $x = y$?

Comment: This is a sorting procedure(almost). What are the conditions required to be satisfied by the input for sorting them? Are there any restrictions you know of?

Comment: @greybeard how about now: x≤y ∨ y≤x and u1≤u2 ?

Comment: Looks complete, but you don't need equality on both sides: in $x \lt y \lor y \le x$, each of the "comparisons" coincides with the preconditions in either "then" or "else" statement.

Comment: @greybeard yeah sorry I accidentally added that, but this is valid right? But I just realised I left out an important detail: "You should consider that the postcondition should be such that we know the initial values of both x and y occur in the set {u1, u2}."

Answer (score 0):

Postcondition $u_1 \leq u_2$ would work, and make in the beginning of the program assertion $ \text{True} $ simply,

Consider the following scheme:

$$
\text{if } \text{cnd then } p_1 \text{ else } p_2
$$

where $p_1$ and $p_2$ are assertions. Let's derive the Weakest Precondition (WP) for this scheme:

In the $\text{else}$ part, we have $u_1 = y$ and $u_2 = x$. From the post-condition, we derive the weakest preconditions:

$$
\text{WP}\{u_1=y; u_2=x\} (u_1 \leq u_2) \text{ will be } p_2 : y \leq x
$$

In the $\text{if}$ part:

$$
\text{WP}\{u_1=x; u_2=y\} (u_1 \leq u_2) \text{ will be } p_1 : x \leq y
$$

Now, these will be assertions in the $\text{else}$ and $\text{if}$ parts, respectively.

Consider the scheme:

$$
\text{if } \text{cnd then } p_1 \text{ else } p_2
$$

The WP of this scheme will be:

$$
\text{cnd} \land p_1 \lor \lnot \text{cnd} \land p_2, \text{ which equals } (x < y \land x \leq y) \lor (x \geq y \land x \geq y) = (x < y \lor x \geq y) = \text{True}
$$

Since $ \text{True} \Rightarrow \text{True} $ is true, it means that the Weakest Precondition is satisfied. Our assertion
  in the beginning satisfies it, implying that our program is locally consistent and terminates since it's loop-free (loop-free
  $\Rightarrow$ termination needs more formalism). Thus, we have proved that the post-condition $u_1 \leq u_2$ is satisfied,
  and no additional constraints on the variables $x$ and $y$ are needed in the beginning.

Comment: but the precondition for the if statement is x<y and not x≤y

Comment: that is cnd written in if statement, it's indeed x<y, but it's not a precondition, it's part of the code, as I've mentioned, precondition "True" would work as well.